# How to remove all characters starting from a specific index character in Shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

```
K="Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100"
echo ${K//[a-zA-Z]/}
```

**Output**

---

```
75.0.3770.100
```

**Expected Output**

---

```
75
```

Need to remove all the characters starting from a specific index character; say **`.`**

Comment: `extglob` is much shorter than `sed "s/^[^0-9]*\([^.][^.]*\).*$/\1/" <<< $K`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extglob` to get this done in single step:

```
shopt -s extglob

K="Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100"
echo "${K//@([a-zA-Z ]|.*)/}"
```

```
75
```

**Expression Details:**

- `@(...)`: Match one of the expressions inside `(...)` separated by `|`
- `[a-zA-Z ]`: Match `[a-zA-Z]` letters or space
- `|`: or
- `.*`: Any string starting from a dot

Comment: The bash 4 `extglob` *parameter expansion* extensions are still a part of man bash, that while you know exactly where it is, after all the years of using bash without them, it is still somewhat of an "Oh why didn't I think of that first!" type deal... I got to use them more `:)`